# Add function after a forEach loop finishes all iterations

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a function that loops trough saved photos and documents on a ionic app and uploads them to a backend.  What I would like to do is add a message that displays after all images/files have been uploaded.  I tried a .then() but this fires during the photo uploading.  The uploading is async.  I believe I may have to use the .map, but unsure how this would work?

ts.

```
upLoadStoredDocuments(auditName: string, i: string | number ) {
  this.STORAGE_KEY_DOC = 'app_DOCS';
  this.storage.get(this.STORAGE_KEY_DOC).then(documents => {
    if (documents) {
      let arr = JSON.parse(documents);
      this.documents = [];
      for (let doc of arr) {
        let filePath = this.file.dataDirectory + doc;
        let resPath = this.pathForFile(filePath);
        this.documents.push({ name: doc, path: resPath, filePath: filePath });
      }
    }
  }).then(() => {
    this.documents.forEach(
       // this.startUpload uploads the photos files
      (imgEntry, position) => this.startUpload(imgEntry, position));
  }).then(() => {
    // fires during image uploading not after
    this.presentToastPhoto('show after done.');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guest that `startUpload` is `async` function which returns [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Then what you need is to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to generate one promise from all `this.startUpload` responses and return that promise in `then` clause:

```js
.then(() => {
    return Promise.all(
        this.documents.map(
            // this.startUpload uploads the photos files
            (imgEntry, position) => this.startUpload(imgEntry, position))
    );
  })
```

To sum up, the issue is that you don't wait for `startUpload` to finish. You need await each response. I used [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wrap a list of promises into one promise (which is resolved then all promises are finished) and returned it in then clause.

Answer (score 0):

make a variable starts at zero
increase it with each loop in foreach

if the variable == the length of files array

show the message

Comment: It won't work, because he loops without waiting for any response. So you will instantly loop the whole array.